# Track Woocommerce error content with TagManager and GA4

Tags: woocommerce, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

For my e-commerce created with Woocommerce I'm trying to track the errors on the checkout page.

At the moment I can track them with GTM and GA4 by triggering an event when the .woocommerce-error error box pops up.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to save the contents of the box into a GTM variable and pass it to the GA4 event.

In this way I expect to be able to analyze how many and which are the errors in the checkout.

This is the error banner code:

```html
<ul class="woocommerce-error" role="alert">
<li data-id="billing_phone">
 ERROR MESSAGE
</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance if anyone will be able to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to GTM preview, preview the error happening, open Variables tab, see which one contains the element in question. If I'm not mistaken, it should be the {{Click Element}}. Or maybe the auto-event variable. Just make one auto event and save it before previewing for it to show in vars. Now you can use it in a CJS like so: {{Click Element}}.innerText

Another way is making a variable that instead of grabbing the {{Click Element}} or the auto event var would just use document.querySelector  using your selector and the rest is the same.